# Access to an embedded document from another embedded document in mongo engine

Tags: python, mongodb, mongoengine

I have a document in mongo engine which has an embedded document. Here is my models:

```
class Problem(EmbeddedDocument):
    id = ObjectId()

class Result(EmbeddedDocument):
    problem = ReferenceField('Problem')

class Contest(Document):
    problem = EmbeddedDocumentField(Problem)
```

Now I want to access to a `Problem` from `Result` model. How can I do it?

Comment: Could you please explain how you data structure should look at the end? I think there might be some duplicate information mixing embedding documents and references to documents.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The fundamental difference between `EmbeddedDocument` and `Document` is that `EmbeddedDocument` exists only inside `Document`.

> `EmbeddedDocument` is a `Document` that **isn’t** stored in **its own collection**. `EmbeddedDocuments` should be used as fields on Documents through the `EmbeddedDocumentField` field type.

Hence `EmbeddedDocument` can't has primary key, `EmbeddedDocument` it is just a dict inside a document. Detailed in [documentation](http://docs.mongoengine.org/apireference.html#mongoengine.EmbeddedDocument)

`id = ObjectId()` this is not a declaration of a field. All possible fields are listed  [there](http://docs.mongoengine.org/guide/defining-documents.html#fields). Due to declare primary key field you need to use `primary_key=True` in a Field's arguments.

`problem = ReferenceField('Problem')` `EmbeddedDocument` can't be reference, because it's not a Field. Thus the correct way to declare embedded field looks like this: `problem = EmbeddedDocumentField(Problem)`